# Select specific CSV columns (Filtering) - Python/pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a very large CSV File with 100 columns. In order to illustrate my problem I will use a very basic example.

Let's suppose that we have a CSV file.

> ```
> in  value   d     f
> 0    975   f01    5
> 1    976   F      4
> 2    977   d4     1
> 3    978   B6     0
> 4    979   2C     0
> ```

I want to select a specific columns.

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv("ThisFile.csv")
```

In order to select the first 2 columns I used

```
data.ix[:,:2]
```

In order to select different columns like the 2nd and the 4th. What should I do?

There is another way to solve this problem by re-writing the CSV file. But it's huge file; So I am avoiding this way.

Comment: can't you do say, `data.value` and `data.f`? is that what you're asking for?

Answer (score 23):

This selects the second and fourth columns (since Python uses 0-based indexing):

```
In [272]: df.iloc[:,(1,3)]
Out[272]: 
   value  f
0    975  5
1    976  4
2    977  1
3    978  0
4    979  0

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

`df.ix` can select by location or label. `df.iloc` always selects by location. When indexing by location use `df.iloc` to signal your intention more explicitly. It is also a bit faster since Pandas does not have to check if your index is using labels.

---

Another possibility is to use the `usecols` parameter:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("ThisFile.csv", usecols=[1,3])
```

This will load only the second and fourth columns into the `data` DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks ! One last thing, I got problem while trynig iloc, I got this problem. "IndexError: too many indices"

Comment: You might have gotten that error, "Too many *indexers*", if the parentheses were omitted, as in `df.iloc[:,1,3]`.

Answer (score 10):

If you rather select column by name, you can use

```
data[['value','f']]

   value  f
0    975  5
1    976  4
2    977  1
3    978  0
4    979  0
```

Answer (score 1):

As *Wai Yip Tung* said, you can filter your dataframe while reading by specifying the name of the columns, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("ThisFile.csv")[['value','d']]
```

This solved my problem.