# Extracting columns from CSV using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to extract the Start Station from a csv file, example data below.

```
Start Time,End Time,Trip Duration,Start Station,End Station,User Type,Gender,Birth Year

1423854,2017-06-23 15:09:32,2017-06-23 15:14:53,321,Wood St & Hubbard St,Damen Ave & Chicago Ave,Subscriber,Male,1992.0
```

The problem I am having is when I try to extract the data I receive the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'start'

```
def load_data(city, month, day):

# load data file into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(CITY_DATA[city])
```

I believe my problem stems from converting the Start Station, but can't seem to figure why.

```
# convert the Start Station column to dataframe
df['Start Station'] = pd.DataFrame(df['Start Station'])

# extract street names from Start Station and End Station to create new columns
df['start'] = df['Start Station'].start

def station_stats(df):
"""Displays statistics on the most popular stations and trip."""

# TO DO: display most commonly used start station
popular_start_station = df['start']
print(popular_start_station)
```

Comment: i think you are assigning a dataframe to a column instead of series

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing. Just try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(CITY_DATA, index = True) # load data file into a one df
start_data_series = df[['Start Station']] # create series with column of interest
```

You can add more columns to the second line according to your liking. For further reading, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394598/select-specific-csv-columns-filtering-python-pandas) post.

Comment: This method returns the column as a Series datatype. How can I extract it as a DataFrame type?